# Как сделать чтобы в форме, если нет нужного клиента, добавить его?

Tags: python, django

Столкнуться с такой проблемой: есть модель клиента и есть модель заказа. Связаны через М2М. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если нет в форме нужного клиента, добавить его. В модальном окне. Но я не знаю как это правильно сделать... Может поможете объяснением и примером кода? Спасибо!

Comment: Что конкретно нужно ? Открыть форму добавления клиента по кнопке ? Как в админке ?

Comment: Milky, да. Примерно так сделать хотелось бы

Comment: Вариантов много. Лично я пошёл путём виджетов, сделал кастомный виджет на основе виджета Select. Добавил туда кнопки, и повесил соответсвующую обработку. Например при нажатии кнопки добавить, отправляем запрос на отрисовку формы конструктора элемента, показываем её пользователю он заполняет и снова отправляет на сервер, и если всё ок, отправляем новый элемент виджета и обновляем элемент который заполняли. Вот пример: https://github.com/WereW10f/new_folder_1

Comment: Milky, спасибо! Буду разбираться))